# Rails how to track user behaviour on video streaming, and save to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, video-streaming

I am still new to rails, and I am trying to build a website that can record how long users watch any video on the website. For example, after user 1 watch video B, I want to know how long the user watched video B not how long he streamed it (only count the part he watched), then send the data back to server, so that I can have a table like below:
User 1 watched video B for 15mins
                          video C for 10mins
User 2 watched video E for 2mins
                          video C for 5mins
How can I calculate the total time user spend on watching? I know there are a lot of player Javascript APIs provide current time when event such as play stop or pause got trigged, but shall I calculate it on client-side? or just send the current time back to server, and calculate it on server-side? Please help me to get a rough solution.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: track the elements with js script and save it into your database.

You must track all possible user events from your page. Hence you can calculate if the user watched, paused or stopped the video. Roughly, you can declare four states: play, stop, pause and exit.

When user clicks in the "play" button, you track these event into your log events with the time. The same for "pause" and "stop". Then to know how much was watched, you just analyze your log table. For instance:

`| id | user | event     | time     |
|----|------|-----------|----------|
| 1  | John | start     | 12:00:00 |
| 2  | John | pause     | 12:01:30 |
| 3  | John | start     | 12:02:00 |
| 4  | John | exit_page | 12:03:00 |`

Tracking the user events, we calculate the time as: 1 min 30 sec (when "John" started and then paused the video) plus 1 min (when "John" started again until he close the page), totalizing 2 min 30 sec.

You will need a js script to sent these events to your backend, and then save it into a log table. Then you retrieve all user actions and do the math.

Of course there are more complex ways, but this is a fast one that can solve your problem our lead you for another solution.